# How to disable python logging stdout and have it just inside the log file

Tags: python, logging

I want to disable my script to print the `INFO`, `DEBUG`, `WARNING` or `ERROR` from logging commands and just have this inside the `.log` or `.err`. Here is the configuration I have:

```
def log(routine_name):
    """ Logging configuration """
    logger = logging.getLogger(_name_)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logging.StreamHandler(stream=None)

    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s")

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(routine_name)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    error_handler = logging.FileHandler(routine_name.replace("log", "err"))
    error_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    error_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    logger.addHandler(error_handler)
    
    return logger
```

I have tried to set `logger.propagate = False` from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460714/python-logging-disable-output-to-stdout) but didn't work, it still printing everything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me this did work with module.submodule issuing the logging commands

```
logger = logging.getLogger("module.submodule")
fh = logging.FileHandler("logfile")
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.disabled = True
```