# How do I eliminate duplicate cPanel logs?

Tags: python, logging, cpanel

When I use `logging`, I get duplicate entries in the log, like this:

```ini
[2022-09-22 11:35:32,079] [INFO] [My App] going to get milk...
App 13621 output: [ pid=13621, time=2022-09-22 11:35:32,079 ]: going to get milk...
```

The second entry, I don't need; it makes the log harder to read.

I have in the past used a log filter command:

```py
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='Unverified HTTPS request')
```

but I don't know how to apply a similar technique to this situation. I'm not sure where the duplicate is coming from so I don't know what to talk to to suppress it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I fixed it by setting:

```py
logger.propagate = False
```

in my logger setup code.

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460714/python-logging-disable-output-to-stdout), and it may be a duplicate question, but the search terms are completely different. I had to figure out `stdout` was involved and search on that term before I found that other solution. Simply searching on the problem symptoms doesn't land you on that page.